# Need a workflow to implement two actions Approve and Actioned

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I have a scenario to implement in my project as a Work Flow where, when an item is created by Submitter, the items should get approved by a Approver along with comments. Once it is approved and implemented in the organization the item status should be updated to Actioned.

Flow Should be like below.

Submitter --Submits--> Status=Pending --> Alerts to Approver/Admin;
Approver --Approves--> Status=Approved --> Alerts Submitter as Approved;
Approver --Rejects--> Status=Rejected --> Alerts Submitter as Rejected

If Item is Approved, then

Approver --Actions--> Status=Actioned --> Alerts Submitter/Approver as actioned.

If rejected, there should not be any action.

I need the above flow in one or more workflows.

Please help me in providing the solution for the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple approval workflow and modify this according to your business requirements.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/sharepoint-server-help/use-an-approval-workflow-HA010154425.aspx

You can also use Simple sahrepoint designer workflows.

http://plexhosted.com/billing/knowledgebase/226/How-to-create-a-simple-approval-workflow-in-SharePoint-Designer.html

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the info. Here I need 2 actions by same team. On creation of new item by Submitter team. the approver should validate the item and approve it. Once it is approved it should be implemented in the system and the status should be changed to "Actioned" by Approver again. How this actioned can be added after the item is Approved

Comment: You can use Update list item to change the status of the listitem after it is approved.